# Is there a way in Cocoa to know if a NSTextField is dirty ? If it has been edited?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there a way in Cocoa to know if a `NSTextField` is dirty ? If it has been edited ?

I know there is the delegate method:

```
- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification;
```

but I would like to know after the editing, when I'm closing the window if the `NSTextField` has been edited.

Comment: The question is, why? Is it simply so you can commit any of those pending edits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In delegate method - `textDidBeginEditing` or `textDidChange` you can set a bool variable, and later you can check the value of that bool variable.

Comment: Ya, but I have 95 different fields. I would prefer to not use 95 booleans.

Comment: then i will prefer creating a category/subclass of NSTextFeild, where you can have a method like 'isEdited`.

Comment: Yep.  A subclass of NSTextField with an "isEdited" field (which gets set whenever "`textDidChange`" fires) would be a smart solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to compare the "before" and "after" values of your "`NSTextField`" object via delegate methods, you could always compare the "before" and "after" values of the "`NSTextField`" objects *without* using delegates when the window is being closed or dismissed.

In other words, save a copy of the contents of the "`NSTextField`" as the window / view appears and then compare the previously saved contents to the current contents.  Then you'll see your differences.

Since you have 95 different fields (wow!) and are likely setting those fields from somewhere, why not programatically enumerate through the 95 different fields and compare them to the previously saved strings to see how many of them changed?

Comment: as commented in the other answer, I have many text fields, I would prefer to not have to save a variable for each field where to save the contents.

Comment: I edited my answer a bit.  If you're setting 95 fields, you're setting them from somewhere, some structure.  Why not enumerate through the 95 text fields as the window is closing, comparing the current value of each text field to what it was previously saved as?

Comment: Because there is another issue: I'm editing multiple items. So I can't compare the original value, because they might be different values. I need to update the value (for all items) connected with the NSTextField I'm currently editing only if the NSTextField has been edited.

Comment: The only thing I can think is to use a boolean as @rishi suggests. But it doesn't seem to be a good solution.

Comment: Rishi's idea of subclassing NSTextField to add an "edited" property (which gets set if the value changes at all) seems to be the way to go in this case.  I'm +1'ing that. And why do you say it's not a good solution? Is subclassing something you're not comfortable or familiar with? (which is okay to admit to)

Comment: OK, subclass is good, I thought he meant to add a boolean for each field. thanks